# Optimizing a MySql query with multiple iterations

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a query that I am using to construct a set of data, which supposed to contain exactly the top 3 users by rating per each admin ID.
Now because I am clueless how to achieve this using SQL, I am fetching the top users for each admin separately and then pushing them into an array.
More over, since calling sth->fetchAll(), and then array_merge(), will lead to having duplicate array keys on the second iteration and onward, and thus will cause a fatal error, I also have an internal iteration(loop) within the first one, which fetches each row from the result set and pushes it into the array where I keep the formatted result.
which cause n *3 iterations, which are n * 3 -1 too many, in my humble opinion.

Also, a BTW question that has been bothering me for quite a while now:
Is it true that there is no way to bind a parameter or a value to SQL language components such as LIMIT and such with PDO emulated prepared statements disabled?.
code:

```
private function getHotUsers($admins, $count = 3)
    {
        try{
            $conn = DBLink::getInstance();
            $rows = array();
            $sql = "SELECT user_name, user_id, user_group_id FROM users
            WHERE admin_id= :uid  AND status=1 ORDER BY is_hot_user DESC,last_updated DESC LIMIT {$count}";
            $sth = $conn->prepare($sql);
        foreach ($admins as $admin)
        {
            $sth->bindParam(':uid', $admin, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $sth->execute();
            while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $rows[] = $row;
            }
        }
        return $rows;   
        }
}

| Field                | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| user_id               | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| admin_id              | int(20)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_title            | varchar(450)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_desc             | varchar(5000)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_data             | longtext         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_requirements     | varchar(5000)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| user_experience       | varchar(100)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| location_id           | int(11) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| comp_id               | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| role_id               | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_pass_time        | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| last_updated          | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_hot_user           | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| user_internal_id      | int(10)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

INSERT INTO USERS(admin_id, last_updated, is hot_user) 
VALUES
**(1, NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY, 1),(1, NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY, 0), 
(1, NOW() - INTERVAL 100 DAY, 1)**, (1, NOW() - INTERVAL 8 DAY, 0),

**(2, NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY, 1), (2, NOW() - INTERVAL 100 DAY, 1),
(2, NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY, 1),** (2, NOW(), 0),

**(3, NOW(), 0), (3, NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY, 0), (3, NOW() - 100 DAY, 1),**
(3, NOW() - INTERVAL 4 DAY, 0), (3, NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY, 0)

Edited as requested by @VolkerK, in bold are the rows that should be selected by the query, the first 3 hot users, that also have the most recent value in their last_updated column, or just the newest users if there are less hot-users tan 3 for this specific admin

Comment: move the `$sth` manipulation outside of the foreach, otherwise you'll lose one purpose of prepared statements...

Comment: You `prepare` the variable `$sql` yet your SQL string is `$query`

Comment: [How can I use prepared statements with LIKE operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo#15990965)

Comment: "Is it true that there is no way to bind a value to LIMIT with PDO emulated prepared statements disabled?" No, you can do so as with any other operator. You just can't use parameter binding for table or column names.

Comment: Why are all answers getting downvoted on this question without any alternative ideas? One answer even was deleted already. Why?

Comment: Deleted one was simply wrong

Comment: Can you please post your table structure and some example data? Preferably in the form of `CREATE TABLE ...` and `INSERT INTO ...` sql statements.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. it seems that you are already using  the right way.
Though you can bind $count as well.
Also, although calling $sth->fetchAll(), and then array_merge(), will **not** lead to having duplicate keys (which is just impossible, mind you), I wouldn't merge all users into single array anyway, but rather group them by their admin

```
private function getHotUsers($admins, $count = 3)
{
    $conn = DBLink::getInstance();
    $rows = array();
    $sql = "SELECT user_name, user_id, user_group_id FROM topUsers
            WHERE admin_id= :uid  AND status=1 
            ORDER BY is_hot_user DESC,last_updated DESC 
            LIMIT :coint";
    $sth = $conn->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($admins as $admin)
    {
        $sth->bindParam(':uid',   $admin, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sth->bindParam(':count', $count, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sth->execute();
        $rows[$admin] = $sth->fetchAll();
    }
    return $rows;   
}
```

To make some your confusions straight:

- as a matter of dact, fetchAll does no magic creating an array out of nowhere. It does the same loop, internally. So, there is no overhead.
- to get top 3 of anything you need to run a separate query anyway. So, it's ok to tun your queries in a loop
- do not trust your *feelings* but measure **certain numbers**. IF this function runs so slow to hinder whole application - go on with optimizations. If not - there are some other things you can spend time for, I believe

Comment: "So, there is no overhead" Doesn't perform `fetchAll` the loop on the C level instead of the PHP code level? If it does it is a performance gain in many cases.

Answer (score -2):

I wouldn't execute such a query inside a loop. The first solution is to use `… IN (…)` to search for a list of ID's (as suggested by Rob).

Or you just set up the query and the parameters in a loop and execute the statement after the loop.

```
$start = 0;
$limit = 100;
$placeholderArray = $valuesArray = array( );
$i = 0;
foreach( $admins as $adminId )
{
    $placeholderArray[] = sprintf( ' `admin_id` = :admin%d ', $i );
    $valuesArray[sprintf( ':admin%d', $i )] = (int) $adminId;
    $i++;
}

$where = ' (' . implode( ' OR ', $placeholderArray ) . ') ';
$sql = sprintf( 'SELECT user_name, user_id, user_group_id
    FROM topUsers
    WHERE status=1
    %s
    ORDER BY is_hot_user DESC,last_updated DESC
    LIMIT %d,%d;', $where, $start, $limit );

$stmt = $conn->prepare( $sql );
if( $stmt->execute( $valuesArray ) === true )
{
    /* … */
}
```

The limitation to three entries is achieved by limiting the original input to three entries in the array `$admins`.

Comment: this might return something like top 100 for single admin

Comment: Maybe I don't still understand the question correct after reading it the third time.